# ¿Como imprimir funciones en un DataGridView?

Tags: c#

Tengo formulario con una clase donde están las variables y también funciones.

Para mostrarlos en el `DataGridView` uso

```
DataGridView.DataSource = List<T>;
```

Pero también quiero que se muestren las funciones por ejemplo

La suma de dos datos que estan en la clase

(Las funciones ya estan creadas)

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar el `getter` de una propiedad para hacerlo, un ejemplo, podría ser algo así

```
    public int Suma
    {   get
        {
            return FuncionEjemplo();
        }
    }

    public int FuncionEjemplo()
    {
        return 1 + 2;
    }
```

Saludos!